# What is an injection in a topos?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, definition, topos-theory

I am reading the [paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9932307&fileId=S0960129513000406) of Andrej Bauer that proves there is a realizability topos in which there is an injection from the internal Baire Space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.
This is discussed in Andrej's [blog](http://math.andrej.com/2011/06/15/constructive-gem-an-injection-from-baire-space-to-natural-numbers/) too.

My question is about the definitions. What does it mean when we say that there is an injection or a surjection in the internal logic of a topos? Does an injection correspond to a monomorphism and a surjection to an epimorphism? Can I please, get some references to that definition if it is true.

If that is not the case, then I am very confused because morphisms in a realizability topos are not functions (for example by taking the exact completion of the category of the assemblies of a partial combinatory algebra) and so one cannot talk about injectivity or surjectivity.
Or is the existence of the injection implied by some other means, i.e. the injection does not correspond to a specific morphism in the topos by rather an object or a class of morphisms and objects with specific properties.

Comment: You can always talk about injectivity in a topos with respect to the internal language; that is, whether $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ internally. Though if I recall, in a topos injective and monomorphic coincide...

Comment: @MaliceVidrine A topos is a category that has finite limits, is cartesian closed and has a subobject classifier. These conditions do not imply that morphisms should be functions. Therefore I do not know how it could be possible to express $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$ in a topos. So what do you mean by stating that injective and monomorphic coincide? Where can I learn more about the internal language of a topos?

Comment: Yes, I know what a topos is. Any introductory topos theory book should have a section on the Mitchell-Benabou language. If no one gets to it before I have a chance, I'll write a proper answer later, but the main idea is that you can interpret logical operators, quantifiers, and equality predicates as special morphisms in the topos itself.

Comment: @Dávid: the statement "$f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$" needs to be interpreted in the internal language, not as a statement about sets and functions. This "internal language" business is a way to interpret statements that look like they're about sets and functions in various categories, such as topoi. So the answer to your second question in fact answers your first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question: Andrej meant "monomorphism".

Since the objects of a topos don't typically consist of (raw, unstructured) sets, the usual notions of injectivity and surjectivity don't apply. But for convenience, people still talk about "injections" and "surjections" in those contexts (and mean monomorphisms and epimorphisms, respectively). This is also common when dealing with abelian categories.

The story doesn't end here. Malice is right with their comment. The *internal language* of a topos allows you to formulate statements about objects of the topos in a naive, element-based way. The *Kripke–Joyal semantics* translates such formulas to external ones. It turns out that the translation of the internal statement "the map $f$ is injective" is precisely "the morphism $f$ is a monomorphism".

You can learn about the internal language in the sections VI.5, VI.6, and VI.7 of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's excellent textbook *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*. I also found [lecture notes by Thomas Streicher](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/CTCL.pdf) very nice and very useful. Of course there's also an [nLab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic). If you prefer slides, then you can have a look at [these slides](http://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/slides-cambridge2016.pdf) of mine which accompany [expository notes](http://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf). (Please don't hesitate to contact me should you have any questions.) The translation of injectivity to being a monomorphism is shown in detail in Example 2.3 on page 8, however in the slightly different setting of a sheaf topos instead of a realizability topos.

I think that the internal language of a topos is a fascinating topic, since it allows you to "explore alternate mathematical universes". But you probably don't need it in order to understand Andrej's nice article. In case you want to refresh your knowledge on realizability, Andrej has [very nice notes](http://math.andrej.com/data/c2c.pdf) about it.

Comment: Let me add a fine print. The translation of "$f$ is injective" is "$f$ is a monomorphism" only if you define injectivity in the constructibly sensible way "if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $x = y$". If instead you define it as "if $x \neq y$, then $f(x) \neq f(y)$" (which is equivalent in classical logic), then the resulting translated notion will be a weaker notion than being a true monomorphism. The internal language of a topos is in general intuitionistic (meaning that the law of excluded middle and the law of double negation elimination are not available) and only seldomly classical.

Comment: I might add that in the case of realizability, if you know the approach of getting a realizability topos from the associated tripos, then you've already seen some internal language at work: the morphisms of the realizability topos are the "internally functional" $\mathcal{P}(\Lambda)$-valued relations (where $\Lambda$ is your PCA).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I have constructed the realizability topos only as the exact completion of the category of the assemblies Ass of the PCA following the construction from John Longley's PhD thesis. In Ass the relation from X to Y is a monomorphism $R \to X \times Y$. As of now,I am very new to the topic and so I do not know yet, what this could mean in the internal language of a topos.